# Different value passed for cardnum begins with 0 in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, return-value

I notice as I'm trying to pass the value of cardnum, date and str to another page which is updatestaffshift page, and after echo the cardnum value, it appears to be a different value than the correct cardnum. However it only occur for cardnum begins with number **0**. Numbers other than 0 the passing value is correct. I have included the output of my result. Please advice on what is wrong with this. Thank you.

```
function updatestaffshift(cardnum,date,str)
{
  var xmlhttp;    
  if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","updatedata/updatestaffshift.php?u="+str+"&cardnum"+cardnum+"&date="+date,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

***Echo card no***

```
 $sql=" SELECT * FROM staff_detail";
 $query = mysqli_query($sql);  

 $int = 0;
 while ($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
 
 $cardnum[$int] = $rr['cardnum'];
 echo "Correct Card No :" ; echo $cardnum[$int];
```

***updatestaffshift.php - Echo passed value***

```
  echo 'Passed Value of Card No : '; echo $cardnum =  $_GET['cardnum'];
```

***Output of result***

[image]

Comment: What is your workflow here? Where is this value selected from, how is it passed to the AJAX call, when is the AJAX call made...? Have you determined at which point this value becomes the wrong one? Have you done any debugging within AJAX?

Comment: A leading zero in an integer means "this is octal" to PHP.